# Android: Show all contacts sorted by favorites

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

I know how to fetch all contacts as well as how to fetch the favorited contacts. 
Is there a way to combine the two and sort by favorites?

```
getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, "starred=?", new String[] {"1"}, <sort by favorites?>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this query to get all contacts order by favorites and then by display name.

```
getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
null, 
null, 
null,
ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED + " DESC, " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC");
```

Comment: This works by getting all contacts sorted by favorites descending, however the other non favorite contacts are sorted in no particular order :( Also why does this work only with sort order DESC and not ASC ?

Comment: If you want to query the favorites contacts first you should choose DESC order because Starred column is 1 for favorite and 0 for no no favorite. I'll change my answer to help you out with the ordering.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. I think you missed a + after " DESC, " Kindly edit your answer to reflect that so that I can accept your answer as the solution :)